Can I request an image by filename with the cloudflare image API and also get its metadata?
With cloudflare's Image API I can easily GET an image by filename.
However, the docs do not show an example of making a request for a single, exact-match image filename, AND also include its metadata.
I guess its alluding that I'd have to make a second request for metadata via the Image Details EP.
Is this the only possible way?
curl --request GET \
 --url 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/ID/images/v2?search=angular.png&search_field=filename&search_exact=true' \
 --header 'Authorization: Bearer BEARER' \
 --header 'Content-Type: application/json'

The above returns many images even though I've specified filename and search_exact
